# Is there a better way to do a shingled roof, than an array mod with object offset?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I'm trying to create a pagoda style roof shingle effect, and this is about as close as i can get it to the look I want after about 45 minutes of tweaking and adjusting the scale and rotation of the empty. I know there's probably a better and faster way to do this. I thought maybe dupliverts was an option but I'm not sure how to make each shingle shorten as it goes along.
[image]

[image]

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21448/how-to-avoid-objects-intersecting-eachother/21492#21492

Comment: thank you for your response. I actually figured out that i needed to set the object origin to the very bottom of the shingle piece so it scaled only towards that part. once i got the general size i just used the good old knife tool to cut off what i didnty need