# Cap a beveled curve with a half-circle

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves

I have a curve beveled with a rectangle. I want to cap this curve with a half-circle as shown on the right. The capped curve should be a single object (even if the curve must be converted to a mesh).

Note: to achieve the capped curve in the example, I cut a cylinder in half and manually rotated it until it somewhat matched the angle of the curve's termination point. Obviously, this solution is far from ideal. Thanks.

[image: The goal]

Comment: Read also:[How do I add a non-deformed end cap to a tube?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53523/how-do-i-add-a-non-deformed-end-cap-to-a-tube)

Comment: I reviewed this other question. Unfortunately, I cannot get the hook to work because the terminating point of the curve is at a weird angle (and must be at that angle).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with an array modifier and a curve modifier.

Similar to this post:

[How to avoid objects intersecting eachother](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21448/how-to-avoid-objects-intersecting-eachother/21492#21492)

Make 2 pieces, a straight section and the end one, and a curve to control the way the array curves and twists.

[image]

Move the main piece so that the object and the curve have their origins on the same spot.

[image]

Use an array modifier, set it to use the curve.

[image]

Then add a curve modifier, so that the array follows the curve.

In the array modifier you can set Start and End caps. Set the end to use the endcap object.

[image]