# How can I bend/warp this as a whole mesh?

Tags: modeling

I'm not the most experienced with blender and I've come along this problem while working on a roof of a building. I'm trying to bend the corners up slightly as Japanese Pagoda's would do, yet my whole mesh will not bend, rather only pieces. Even when I've combined all the layers, it will not work in unison (the screenshots do not portray the layers being combined together). To summarize, I need to bend the corners up slightly with everything moving together and without clipping. The second picture shows me grabbing the main layer and moving it, yet it does the same thing when everything is combined into one singular layer. Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What method do you use? the Surface Deform modifier?

Comment: Edges don't bend. You need more subdivisions to create curvature. To bend you might want to try using a lattice modifier. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DUcPXLI9ATk

Comment: See also: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21448/how-to-avoid-objects-intersecting-eachother/21492#21492